# How can I do an array of map objects in Dart

Tags: arrays, dictionary, dart

I'm new to Dart and Flutter and I can't figure it out,
I want to create an array in which each element is a map object, so that I can reference it with something like : thisVar = myArray[0]['myElement'].
So that I can dynamically access different item from different array indexes.

```
//this is in my data file
var tox = [
  {"icon": Icons.help, "color": Colors.black38, "text": "Inconnue"},
  {"icon": Icons.check_circle, "color": Colors.green, "text": "C'est bon"},
  {"icon": Icons.error, "color": Colors.yellow[500], "text": "À l'occasion"},
  {"icon": Icons.cancel, "color": Colors.amber[500], "text": "Douteux"},
  {"icon": Icons.cancel, "color": Colors.orange[800], "text": "Toxique"},
  {"icon": Icons.cancel, "color": Colors.red[900], "text": "Très toxicité"},
];

// this is in my home page
Column(children: <Widget>[
            Icon(tox[0]['icon'],
                 color: tox[0]['color']),
            Text(tox[0]['text']),
      ],
)
```

I get the error : Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'

Comment: Are you sure about the code? It seems strange that you have both Colors.black38 and Colors.yellow[500] (where the last one are expected that "yellow" are kind of a list with a element with index 500?) It seems related to you error message.

Comment: The `Colors` values look fine. They are defined in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html and are objects which override the `[]` operator..

Comment: I see no problem with the code. Are you *absolutely sure* this is the code giving the error, and that `tox` contains the value you expect?

Comment: I'm sure, when I comment the Icon() and Text() lines within the column children, I don't get any error. And the debugPrint of "tox" seems fine to me...

Comment: I found out my error, there was another instance of a variable named tox that was conflicting with this one. I corrected it, with a more meaningful name, now everything is fine. Thankyou for your help.